# MYSQL RIGHT JOIN

Tags: mysql, join

I have 3 tables; events, memberEvents, and members.

Events: `eventId`, `eventName`, `eventDivision`

memberEvents: `memberID`, `eventOne`, `eventTwo`, `eventThree`, `eventFour`, `eventFive` 

member: `memberID`, `memberFirstName`, `memberLastName`


I am trying to get it to display `events`.`eventName` followed by the `memberFirstName` & `memberLastName` of members that are doing that event


This is the query I have been trying:

> SELECT * FROM `events`, `memberEvents`, `members`
>
> WHERE `events`.`eventDivision` = 'C'
>
> RIGHT JOIN `memberEvents`.`memberID`
>
> ON `events`.`eventID` = `memberEvents`.`eventOne`
>
> OR `events`.`eventID` = `memberEvents`.`eventTwo`
>
> OR `events`.`eventID` = `memberEvents`.`eventThree`
>
> OR `events`.`eventID` = `memberEvents`.`eventFour`
>
> OR `events`.`eventID` = `memberEvents`.`eventFive`
>
> > > When I run this i get "#1066 - Not unique table/alias: 'memberEvents'"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you specifically want to limit the number of events per member to five? Why not just have a memberEvent table that has a primary key made up of foreign keys to member and event?

memberEvent: memberId, eventId

Then your query would be

```
SELECT
event.eventName,
member.memberFirstName,
member.memberLastName 
FROM
event
INNER JOIN
memberEvent
ON
memberEvent.eventID = event.eventId
INNER JOIN
member
ON
memberEvent.memberId = member.memberId
WHERE
event.division = 'C';
```

Maybe you have a good reason for the table structure you have chosen but it is a denormalised design and if you ever need to increase the number of events per member you'll need to modify your schema and code to suit.

Comment: Excellent! It was close enough that it helped get what I was looking for! Thanks a Million!

Comment: I over looked your question, I am learn php/mysql and I really just kinda wasn't sure and made a limit when it wasnt needed. I see what you are saying about using the foreign key an might incorporate that in soon! Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
SELECT ev.*,  me.* FROM events ev
RIGHT JOIN memberEvents me
ON (ev.eventID = me.eventOne
OR ev.eventID = me.eventTwo
OR ev.eventID = me.eventThree
OR ev.eventID = me.eventFour
OR ev.eventID = me.eventFive)
WHERE ev.eventDivision = 'C'
```

Comment: I actually tried this before hand it fails with error: #1066 - Not unique table/alias: 'memberEvents'

Answer (score 0):

I think you should have a closer look at the defenition

[JOIN Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html)

It seems that you have misunderstood the JOIN syntax.

```
SELECT  * 
FROM    table1 t1 right join 
        table2 t2   on  t1.key1 = t2.key1 
                    and t1.key2 = t2.key2 
where   t1.somecolumn = somevalue
```